# Create a private Array that stores 2 hexadecimal digits, typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, hex

I have created a class called Memory. It is supposed to have a private array for hex digits.
I'm using Visual Studio Code for this.

class Memory{

}

Create a private Array that stores 2 hexadecimal digits (8 bits /
1 byte) per array element. The array length should be the total
size of addressable memory and should be initialized as a
hexadecimal number.

I know the difference between hex, binary, and decimal digits but I'm not sure how to implement hex in a private array in typescript.

Comment: Uint8Array perhaps

Comment: ① The privacy of the array seems to have nothing to do with the implementation; could you [edit] to focus on just the array without distractions? ② what's the use case?  I don't understand "the length should be the total size of addressable memory" here; what's "addressable memory"? Surely JavaScript doesn't present memory this way.  ③ Is this a homework question?  If so, such things aren't necessarily off-topic here, but you probably won't get what you need out of your studies by getting someone else to answer for you and you should at least present what you tried.